# Rails 2.3.18 + Unable to hit another application on same domain name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

In my Rails application ( Rails -v 2.3.18 ), I have to pass Net::HTTP.new request to same domain but running on different port and technology. But hosted on same server under same domain name.

Rails App - URL : http://physic.mytest.local/login

Java App - URL : http://physic.mytest.local/student_portal

For login system I am using RailsApp ( having all the details related to User for authentication ). Here I will validate the User via Rails app and  from same controller I will authentication call to Java application to validate the User for student portal. But I am not able to hit the server.

Routes :   `map.student_portal "student_portal", :controller => "user_sessions", :action => "student_portal"`

**UserSession Controller :**

```
def student_portal
  redirect_to "http://physic.mytest.local/student_portal"
end
```

**User Model :**

```
def login_inside_student_portal(username, password)
  cookie_response = ""
  begin
    uri = URI.parse("http://physic.mytest.local/student_portal")

    response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {"userName" => username, "password" => password})
    if response["Set-Cookie"].start_with?("JSESSIONID=")
      cookie_response = response["Set-Cookie"]
    else
      puts "response Set-Cookie .start_with? JSESSIONID"
    end
  rescue => e
    puts "inside - login_inside_student_portal = #{e}"
  end
  return cookie_response
end
```

Please suggest something.

Comment: Is there any server that's routing /login to rails app and /student_portal to Java app? What is the port the rails app is running on, and what is the port Java app is running. You should just direct your URI directly to Java application port directly without going thru the domain.

Comment: Sir did you try curl to hit the server first ? .... hope the server is down

Comment: @Alexander: Thanks for suggestion.
RajarshiDas : Msg after long time. I sought out the problem. In nginx, we forgot to mention the URL ie physic.mytest.local as valid domain.